# Extend resource path in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

I am new to Ruby and Rails, so question may look trivial to you.

Here is a snippet from the route file to explain what I am asking for:

```
namespace :admin do

  resources :database_managers
  post :admin_database_managers_path/some_extension_here, as database_managers_extended
end
```

since I already have this `database_managers` resources I want to extend it using the resources path. So when the resources path change the extended routes to be extended too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for.

```
namespace :admin do
  resources :database_managers do
    collection do
      post :some_extension_here
    end
  end
end
```